# How can I save a NSString public key in the key chain and then get a SecKeyRef of it?

Tags: ios5, nsstring, keychain

I have a `NSString` which is supposed to be a *public key*. I want to store it in the keychain and then get a `SecKeyRef` of it, in order to use it in other security related functions like `SecKeyEncrypt`, etc.

For storing I use the `SecItemAdd` supposing that I also have an identifier for the public key. I tried to get a persistent ref and then with this get a `SecKeyRef` with `SecItemCopyMatching`. I use the below two functions. Before I pass the string of key to `putKey` I converted it to `NSData`.

```
-(SecKeyRef)putKey:(NSData *)key withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier 
{
    OSStatus status = noErr;
    SecKeyRef keyRef = nil;
    CFTypeRef persKey = nil;

    NSData * identifierTag = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:(const void *)[identifier UTF8String] length:[identifier length]];
    NSMutableDictionary *queryKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [queryKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [queryKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [queryKey setObject:identifierTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryKey setObject:key forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    [queryKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnPersistentRef];

    status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryKey, (CFTypeRef *)&persKey);

    if (status == errSecDuplicateItem) NSLog(@"Key %@ already exists in the KeyStore, OSStatus = %ld.", identifier, status);
    else if (status != noErr) NSLog(@"Error putting key %@ in KeyStore, OSStatus = %ld.", identifier, status);

    keyRef = [self getKeyRefWithPersistentKeyRef:persKey];

    return keyRef;
}

- (SecKeyRef)getKeyRefWithPersistentKeyRef:(CFTypeRef)persistentRef
{
    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    SecKeyRef keyRef = NULL;

    if (persistentRef == NULL) NSLog(@"persistentRef object cannot be NULL.");

    NSMutableDictionary * queryKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Set the SecKeyRef query dictionary.
    [queryKey setObject:(__bridge id)persistentRef forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValuePersistentRef];
    [queryKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnRef];

    // Get the key reference.
    sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryKey, (CFTypeRef *)&keyRef);

    return keyRef;
 }
```

The `SecItemAdd` returns successfully a persistent key ref.

But `SecItemCopyMatching` returns 0x0. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Apple's [Crypto Exercise](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html).  In order to add a public key to the KeyChain, it is necessary to strip off the header that is attached to it.  Apple's example shows doing just that, and the code is easy to reuse.